# Spring boot standalone tomcat HttpServletResponse always returning status 200

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot, http-status-codes

I am using spring boot version 1.1.8 , I have the following interceptor intercepting all the incoming http requests, one functionality, is to print the response status code on the post handle

```
public class TimingInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
private static final String TIME_ATTR = "startTime";

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Object handler) throws Exception {
    request.setAttribute(TIME_ATTR, System.currentTimeMillis());
    boolean hasQuery = StringUtils.isNotEmpty(request.getQueryString());
    log.info("[START] method={} path={} {}{}", request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURI(),
            hasQuery ? "?" : "", hasQuery ? request.getQueryString() : "");
    return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);

}

@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    try {
        long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - (long) request.getAttribute(TIME_ATTR);

        log.info("[FINISH] method={} path={} status={}  [time={}] Milisec",
                request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURI(), response.getStatus(), duration);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error while measuring timing", e);
    }
    super.postHandle(request, response, handler, modelAndView);
}
```

}

When running on embedded tomcat the statuses are as expected ,for example in this case:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/test")
public ResponseEntity<Void> test(HttpServletResponse response) {
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

The interceptor will print 201 which is (CREATED) but when running on standalone tomcat the interceptor will print 200 also tried this way

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/test")
public ResponseEntity<Void> test(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setStatus(201);
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

But without success, any ideas what is wrong ? will appreciate the help!

Comment: When you are using the standalone tomcat, how are you configuring it? How are you deploying it? How are you producing your war? By 'printing' do you mean 'returns to the browser with status code xx'?

Comment: Dave below basically diagnosed the problem.. can you suggest any workaround? thanks

Comment: Ultimately, the instance of the filter is available in your application's context. I suppose you could write a context aware bean that could remove the filter from the context. Or, you could fork the git repository containing the filter, patch the code so that it works correctly, submit a pull request to the project lead, and use your own patched version until it is released.

Answer (score 0):

That's the `ErrorPageFilter` from Spring Boot wrapping the `HttpServletResponse`. Probably a bug.

Comment: Dave, how are you figuring that out? The 200 means successful, and I can't see anything in the question relating to error page filters. Am I missing something?

Comment: Look at the `ErrorPageFilter` it masks the status.

Comment: It's not as bad as it looks because the caller will still see the 201. Only the filter chain downstream of the `ErrorPageFilter` sees the 200. Issue for tracking: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2367.

Comment: Thanks for following .. the scenario is exactly like you said the caller gets the right status. is there anything suggestions as a workaround which is not printing the status in every controller method? I need it for logging purposes thanks

Comment: You can probably add a `Filter` (and make it `PriorityOrdered` so it comes before the `ErrorPageFilter`).

Comment: I tried to do what you suggesting without success..tried to set the filter order to 0 and MAX_INT the filter is working but still got 200 as status in each response, any ideas?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try it. If you just want to log the status you could let the container do it. Tomcat has an `AccessLogValve` for instance.

Comment: Hey, I saw you committed a fix! when it will be available and in which spring boot version?

Comment: The fix is in 1.1.x and on master, so whenever the next releases come out, that's when it's available.